# Calling getAttachmentContentAsync on an email left open for more than 5 minutes results in a 401 error

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Steps to reproduce:

```
1. Open Add-in on an email item with attachments (OWA against O365 on Chrome)  
2. Wait > 5 or so minutes  
3. Attempt to download attachment content using getAttachmentContentAsync  
4. Observe callback with generic error
```

Looking at outbound XHR's in dev console. I see a GET to this url below

```
https://attachments.office.net/owa/jules.wada@sfdcmsft.com/service.svc/s/GetFileAttachment?id={attachmentId}&token={attachmentDownloadToken}&isDownload=true&animation=true&asDataUri=true
```

This requests 302's with a redirect url of (It looks like office.js is attempting to refresh the attachmentDownloadToken)

https://outlook.office.com/owa/jules.wada@sfdcmsft.com/service.svc/s/GetAttachmentDownloadToken?redirect={encodedRedirectParams}

which then returns a 401. Is this behavior expected?

Switching between emails refreshes the attachmentDownloadToken, but getAttachmentContentAsync does not seem to do so.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We have been able to reproduce this successfully and placed it on our backlog of work items. We don't have an ETA to communicate yet regarding the resolution of this issue. Can you let us know the exact scenario for which you need to wait for >5 minutes?

Comment: I left my email open while navigating a different browser window. Then launched my add-in and attempted to download attachments through office.js getAttachmentContentAsync. Re-opening the add-in doesn't suffice, only by switching between emails does this issue resolve.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: We re-looked at the issue and it can no longer be reproduced. Can you try it again in your environment?